# Delete the table row of the Last Triggered Button jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to delete the row where the triggered button is. Every row has a button that calls a div or form. After the event on that div or form by clicking back, row should be deleted.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M3W2L/2/)

```
$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').show();
    $('#myTable').hide();   
});

$('#bck').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
    $('#myTable').show();
    alert('DELETE THE ROW OF THE LAST TRIGGERED BUTTON, IF THE USER CLICK Btn 1 THE ROW WITH BTN 1 WILL BE DELETED');
})
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using a static variable:

```
window.btnId = $(this).attr("id");
```

and the closest function

```
$("#"+window.btnId).closest("tr").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M3W2L/4/

Comment: Exactly what I need, but can you explain how's that happen using your method? thank you.

Comment: I stored the id of the button globally. When back pressed, grabbed the button with jquery, and grabbed the closest tr up the chain, and removed it

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/DmWNz/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Sr28Q/

What I did: (for your specific need)

- Store the `id` of the button.
- Extractnumeric value form the id and hook to the `rowid` -- `.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`
- To remove use `.remove()` api : http://api.jquery.com/remove/

**please note** In the HTML the `id` of the 2 buttons were same, they are fixed as well.

Rest should fit the need. `:)`

**code**

```
var rowId;

    $('#btn1, #btn2').click(function () {
        $('#myDiv').show();
        $('#myTable').hide();
        rowId = $(this).prop('id');
    });

    $('#bck').click(function () {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
        $('#myTable').show();
        $('#myRow' + rowId.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')).remove();
        alert('-- ' + rowId);
    });
```